# How to implement a pop up form in hook_page_build

Tags: routes, theming

I'm trying to create a serial validator that pops up when the user goes to download a file. I already have a disclaimer in the [`hook_page_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) but I would like to expand upon this and then ask them to put in the serial number of the product before they are allowed download.